# Android spinner from sqlite - best method?

Tags: android, sqlite

So at the moment I have a simple reminder app that you enter some details, select a data and time and then the app reminds you on the selected date/time.

I now want to be able to add functionality to select categories which I want to select from a spinner, which is populated from separate database table - I will be adding a class to add new categories.

Is an sqlite database the best way of doing this or is there an easier alternative? I assume I will need to make foreign keys/triggers?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think the best way is to use sqlite3, especially if you're mutating data.

Spinner is an `AdapterView` like `ListView` or `GridView`, so you can just use a `CursorAdapter` (or possibly `SimpleCursorAdapter`) to populate it with data from your database.

[This](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/) looks like a decent tutorial for creating a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. In your own code you would call `spinner.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);`

Comment: thanks for that - could this also be achieved by just using an array? populate the names from an array then any queries for sorting could just be based upon the exact name? I guess this approach would create redundant data though.

Comment: Yes, in that case you can use an ArrayAdapter. In general it seems better to use sqlite3 sorting in your query itself and not have to copy the array data. Also if you use an array you will need to copy the changes back to the database manually. With a cursor adapter you would alter the database directly and then call requery() to update the change to your cursor adapter